# Are all arguments held constants in partial derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$F$ be a function of $x,$ $y,$ $z.$ $z$ depends on $x$ and $y.$ Then when evaluating $\partial F/\partial x,$ do I treat $z$ as a constant? I am under the impression that if I don't, what I would get is the total derivative $dF/dx.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are saying , given a function of three variables $G(x,y,z)$ and another function of two variables $g(x,y)$ we define a function of two variables $F(x,y)=G(x,y,g(x,y))$, yes?

Assume that is what you meant. Then, what is $\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}$?  Well, it is $$\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {F(x+h,y)-F(x,y)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {G(x+h,y,g(x+h,y))-G(x,y,g(x,y))}h$$

So you can see that the $z-$component of $G$ is not constant.  The derivative will involve both $\frac {\partial G}{\partial x}$ and $\frac {\partial G}{\partial z}$.  Indeed, it is not difficult to show from this that $$\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac {\partial G}{\partial x}+\frac {\partial G}{\partial z}\frac {\partial g}{\partial x}$$

Example:  say $G(x,y,z)=x+y +z^2$ and let $g(x,y)=2x+3y$.  Then define $$F(x,y)=G(x,y,g(x,y))=x+y+(2x+3y)^2=4x^2+x+y+12xy +9y^2$$

Of course we have $$\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}=8x+1+12y$$

We have the partials for $G$, namely $$\frac {\partial G}{\partial x}=1\quad \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=1 \quad \frac {\partial G}{\partial z}=2z$$

We claim that $$\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac {\partial G}{\partial x}+\frac {\partial G}{\partial z}\frac {\partial g}{\partial x}$$

But the left hand is $$1+ 2z\times 2=1+4(2x+3y)=8x+12y+1$$  which is consistent.

Comment: That doesn't sound like what I was asking. Maybe I was ambiguous. I meant to say that F is a function of x,y, and z (say). And z in turn is a function of x and y. So when evaluating ∂F(x,y,z)/∂x, do I treat z as a constant like I do with y?

Comment: Well perhaps I misinterpreted, though I do not think I did.  Please edit your question to explain precisely what you meant. As it stands, it is not clear. (I note that the other responder has the same confusion I have).

Comment: Note:  I believe that you are only quibbling as to whether the implicit function of three variables ought to be called $F$ or $G$.  I called it $G$ to make it clear that it is different from your $F$ which, after all, is a function of only two variables.

Comment: I do sense that I am wrong somewhere. Could you please point out? I'll explain how I see things : F be a function of x and y and z. z depends on x and y (is saying z is a function of x and y incorrect?). I do not know the precise nature of the dependency. I am not trying to introduce any new function G. I am taking the partial derivative of F w.r.t. x. My question is whether or not I treat z as a constant.

Comment: Right.  You are saying exactly the same thing I am saying only you call my function $G$ by the same name as you call your function of two variables, $F$.  That isn't "wrong" as such but I think it is needlessly confusing.  Anyway, read my post carefully.  Or read the post from @TedShifrin which is more or less identical to mine.  We use different words so I'll leave mine up, but we are saying exactly the same thing.

Comment: I'm beginning to sense this is where I got confused. Why do we need a function of two variables again? Are you saying that since z depends on x and y, we essentially had a function of two variables?

Comment: More emphatically, you only have a function of two variables.  your $F$ just depends on $x,y$.  You may have thought of it by means of a function of three (or thirty-seven) variables but in the end it is just a function of two.  The way you have written your question suggests (strongly) that you started from a function of three variables and are asking how the derivatives of your $F$ relate to the derivatives that other function.

Comment: I'll just tell you where the confusion began. In Sneddon's book, they had the equation F(x,y,z,a,b)=0, where z is dependent on x and y. Differentiating w.r.t. x they got ∂F/∂x + (∂F/∂z)(∂z/∂x) = 0. Now this makes sense to me only if in the first term, we differentiated F w.r.t. x treating z as a constant. Hence, my question : do we hold z constant when taking partial derivative w.r.t. x.

Comment: In that expression both $\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}$ and $\frac {\partial F}{\partial z}$ are computed in the usual way, holding the other four variables constant.

Comment: You can derive that from what I wrote in my post (well, I did it for three variables, but still).  Just note that $g(x+h,y)\approx g(x,y)+h\frac {\partial g}{\partial x}$ and so on.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was being ambiguous in any way. But this is the very question I asked. I even said that let z=g(x,y).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65449/discussion-between-hrit-roy-and-lulu).

Comment: No, it was not.  It's silly for you to argue that your question was clear.  The only people to respond to you were confused by what you wrote.  That means it was not clear.  When I spelled it out, in terms you now agree with, you could not see that it was the same as what you were asking.  Anyway, if you understand now, then all is well.

Comment: I never said I was clear. I have been saying this from the beginning that I am wrong. You perhaps did not understand what I meant by my last comment. You said that the partial derivative was calculated the usual way : holding all other variables constant. That was what I meant to ask. I corrected myself by saying let us consider a function of 3 variables x,y and z. Since you agreed that the variables were all being held constants, the answer to my question in my mind is "yes, we treat z as a constant while differentiating partially w.r.t. x."

Comment: Well, no.  I still think you are confused.  Your post refers to holding $g(x,y)$ constant which makes no sense at all.  Yes, I can compute the derivative of your function in terms of the ordinary partials of a different function.  But that is very, very different from what you asked in your post.

Comment: In your texts example, the dependence of $z$ on $x$ means, in effect that you have a directional derivative, not a standard coordinate partial.  It is a wondrous thing that you can compute directional derivatives using the standard partials.  That's what the formula you cited tells us in this instance.

Comment: Edited the post to change one thing. What else is wrong/confusing?

Comment: I see that edit.  In that context you do not hold the other terms constant.  They aren't constant, after all, they move when you move $x$. Your situation differs from that in your text.  in your text, they are working with a function of $5$ independent variables and they compute $\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}$ in that context.  Your variables are not independent so it is not the same situation.

Comment: If you like, your text is abusing notation a bit (just a little bit though).  They start with a function $F$ of five independent variables.  Then they implicitly define another function, let's call it $f$ of four variables, by setting one of the five to a function of some of the others.  They then remark that you can compute $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}$ out of the ordinary partials of $F$.  Again, your text does not label $f$ by name but that is what they are thinking of.

Comment: Did I say they were independent? In the text z was indeed a function of x and y. Isn't that the case in partial differential equations? I thought I mentioned it. And please correct me wherever I'm wrong.

Comment: In your texts function, the function $F$ clearly started life out as a function of five independent variables.  then you reduce that number by making one of them a function of the others.  Exactly what I did in my post.

Comment: I will edit my post to include an example.

Comment: That sounds like something that I could have missed. Thanks a bunch for taking the time to understand my problem.

Comment: No problem.  My example might clarify things, anyway I hope it does.

Comment: Indeed it has. I see why I was so confused. All the books I read and my professor use $z$ to mean both the variable and the function, whch now I understand to be a messy notation. That's why I never understood that the first function had 5 independent arguments. It actually makes perfect sense to me now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need more careful notation. You start with a function $F(x,y,z)$ and you form a new function $\phi(x,y) = F(x,y,g(x,y))$. Do you mean $\partial F/\partial x$ or do you mean $\partial\phi/\partial x$? [The latter is what you're referring to as the total derivative.] As it stands, your question really is ill-defined, but given the way you phrased it, I would vote unequivocally for the latter; otherwise, you must define the function $F$ with three independent variables.

Comment: Of course when I say ∂F/∂x I mean ∂F(x,y,g)/∂x.

Comment: That makes no sense, though. $g$ is a function, not a variable. Start with $F(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$. Once you put $z=g(x,y)$, you have a function of $x,y$ only. You can't even tell any more what the original $F(x,y,z)$ was once I write $\phi(x,y) = x^2+y^2+(x+y+3e^x)^2$.

Comment: No, I'm not. We've explained it to you and you're not listening.

Comment: By the way, I have taught multivariable calculus in some form or other for approximately 48 years and written a textbook on the subject. So you don't need to be rude.

Comment: Oops. Never meant to sound rude!